Unable to create a function app with a storage account created as AzureDNS endpoint type
I am trying to create a function app using az functionapp create command and providing a storage account name to it but  the storage account is created with --dns-endpoint-type : AzureDNS .  So all the storage endpoints will have z[00-60] added in the middle of the url.
While creating functionapp i am getting this error.
ERROR: There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved: 'cibuildstorage189204.file.core.windows.net'
When i checked Endpoints tab under storage account i noticed the file share endpoint is like this cibuildstorage189204.z30.file.core.windows.net
Any idea how i can attach such storage account to a function app ?
UPDATE:  I managed to get it working with App service plan based function apps but can't get it working with Elastic/Consumption based plans. Can someone help with that ?

I noticed that the function apps that are hosted in Consumption and Elastic Premium plans need file storage to store function code and metadata.
To be able to use AzureDNS based storage accounts with function apps, the app service plan needs to be App service plan based e.g  Basic, Standard, Premium.  These function apps doesn't use file storage.
After switching plan from Elastic Premium to Premium the function app got created and code deployed. But need to make some code changs where blob,file, table endpoints are directly used in the code. To fix that we need to get the endpoints first through a call and then use them instead of directly using *.blob.core.windows.net etc.
I welcome any other efficient solutions for this problem.
